# Запрос SQL с "разворотом" таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица с информацией по заказам.

[image: таблица]

Пока получается сделать только так:

```
SELECT count(*) as 'Заказы'
  , order_stat as 'Статус'
  , sum(cost_profit) as 'Доход'
  , sum(cost_drop) as 'Затраты' 
FROM `drop`WHERE  DATE(data_order)='2016-09-07' 
GROUP BY order_stat
```

Подскажите, куда "копать", чтобы получить таблицу вида:
**Дата, Подтверждено, Отменено, Отправлено, Итого**,
нужно на сколько понимаю использовать подзапросы.

Благодаря подсказкам все получилось.

```
SELECT DATE(data_order) as 'Дата заказа', 
count(*) as 'заказы',
COUNT(
        CASE 
            WHEN order_stat LIKE '%Отменен%' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'отменен',
COUNT(
        CASE 
            WHEN order_stat LIKE '%Подтвержден%' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'подтвержденн',
COUNT(
        CASE 
            WHEN order_stat LIKE '%Отправленный%' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'отправленный',
COUNT(
        CASE 
            WHEN order_stat LIKE '%Оплаченный%' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE NULL 
        END
    ) AS 'оплаченный',
sum(cost_profit) as 'Доход', sum(cost_drop) as 'Затраты' 
FROM `drop`
GROUP BY DATE(data_order)
ORDER BY `drop`.`data_order` DESC
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Pivot не поддерживает MySQL, так что 3 CASE решат проблему: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page1.html